How to build a query to update a record using CakePHP 4.4 and Slim-4 and MariaDB
The back story on this request is I am using SlimFramwork 4 Skeleton. I have been running it for a couple of years now. I need to update a record in the database. I have this method
 namespace App\Domain\Customer\Data;

 use Cake\Database\Query;

 final class CustomerFinderResult
 {
   /**
    * @var CustomerFinderItem[]
    */
    public array $customers = [];

    private Query $query;

    public function __construct(Query $query)
    {
       $this->query = $query;
    }


public function updateSubscriptionStatus(string $subscriptionId, string $status): void
{
    $query = $this->query->update('customers')
        ->set(['subscription_status' => $status])
        ->where(['paypal_subscription_id' => $subscriptionId]);
    $query->execute();
}

When the method is executed, no records are updated. I made sure that I was passing in strings. I dropped the input data into a log file to verify what I am sending to the method is the correct format and that there is data being passed.
I called on Gemini to help but the query it gave me to run failed because the method it was using does not exist says the error message that I received.
 public function updateSubscriptionStatus(string $subscriptionId, string $status): void
  { 
     $customer = $this->Customers->find()->where(['paypal_subscription_id' => 
     $subscriptionId])->firstOrFail();
     $customer->subscription_status = $status;
     $this->Customers->save($customer);
   }

The find() method is an unknown method call. I looked into the Cake\Database\Query method and found it in the class. The documentation does not shed light on this for me. I checked the class documentation and changed the query after seeing this.
$query->update('articles')->set(['title' => 'The Title'], ['title' => 'string']);

I changed my query to this:
 $query = $this->query->update('customers')
        ->set(
            ['subscription_status' => $status],
            ['paypal_subscription_id' => $subscriptionId]
        );
    $query->execute();

No joy. I am at a loss for what to do next. Any suggestions?
In the Query class for set. there is this.
/**
 * Set one or many fields to update.
 *
 * ### Examples
 *
 * Passing a string:
 *
 * ```
 * $query->update('articles')->set('title', 'The Title');
 * ```
 *
 * Passing an array:
 *
 * ```
 * $query->update('articles')->set(['title' => 'The Title'], ['title' => 'string']);
 * ```
 *
 * Passing a callable:
 *
 * ```
 * $query->update('articles')->set(function ($exp) {
 *   return $exp->eq('title', 'The title', 'string');
 * });
 * ```
 *
 * @param \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression|\Closure|array|string $key The column name or array of keys
 *    + values to set. This can also be a QueryExpression containing a SQL fragment.
 *    It can also be a Closure, that is required to return an expression object.
 * @param mixed $value The value to update $key to. Can be null if $key is an
 *    array or QueryExpression. When $key is an array, this parameter will be
 *    used as $types instead.
 * @param array<string, string>|string $types The column types to treat data as.
 * @return $this
 */
public function set($key, $value = null, $types = [])
{
    if (empty($this->_parts['set'])) {
        $this->_parts['set'] = $this->newExpr()->setConjunction(',');
    }

    if ($key instanceof Closure) {
        $exp = $this->newExpr()->setConjunction(',');
        $this->_parts['set']->add($key($exp));

        return $this;
    }

    if (is_array($key) || $key instanceof ExpressionInterface) {
        $types = (array)$value;
        $this->_parts['set']->add($key, $types);

        return $this;
    }

    if (!is_string($types)) {
        $types = null;
    }
    $this->_parts['set']->eq($key, $value, $types);

    return $this;
}

I will have to find a way to get the query to work properly or go the PDO route to get past this hurdle.

You say "The find() method is an unknown method call." What is $this->Customers when you try to call it? I see nothing in the code presented that would initialize that, and your CustomerFinderResult class seems to be outside the standard application structure so there would be no expectation of it being initialized by default.

Greg, you are right the $this->Customers is what Gemini suggested which is most likely the default structure. Someone else built this skeleton and put in the data call structure. I am trying to figure it out. That is why I showed the class construct. Now, what is happening is that the first call to the database updates all rows in the table. I  have this in a loop to go through an array of subscription IDs. Now, I need find() to work so that it updates the correct row. What a mess!

The answer for me was to use the query factory. Using the query factory. I was able to update the table correctly.
